# E_ADS_SCHEMA_VIOLATION

Tags: delphi, active-directory

Domain 2008 R2, DC. Administrator. DelphiXe2.

I Get User's info with ADOConnection1.SQL:

select 
extensionAttribute1,
extensionAttribute2,
cn,
sn,
givenname,
displayName,
sAMAccountName,
userPrincipalName,
mail,
title,
telephonenumber,
company,
department,
description,
objectSid, 
physicalDeliveryOfficeName,
userAccountControl
from 'LDAP://dc=ru/dc=mydomain/OU=User' 
where 
objectCategory = 'person' and objectClass='user' and 
userAccountControl<>514 
and userAccountControl<>546
order by name

All work normal.
I put new user:

```
Uses ActiveDs_TLB, ActiveX, ComObj;

..
var  Usr: IADsUser;  Comp: IADsContainer;
begin
try
CoInitialize(nil);
Comp:=GetObject('WinNT://localhost') as IADsContainer;
Usr:=comp.Create('user','Koko') as IADsUser;
usr.SetPassword('Fa123456789');
// usr.FirstName:='Pups';
Usr.SetInfo;
except ..
end;
end;
```

Questions:

1. The code above works normally when I add the new user. But if I try to add what or property, for example FirstName (unRem usr. FirstName), I receive error E_ADS_SCHEMA_VIOLATION. How it to treat?
2. Prompt, as by means of properties Usr:IADsUser; to change the expanded attributes, for example "extensionAttribute1"?
3. Whether it is possible to add the new user by means of inquiry ADOConnection1.SQL or to change properties of the specified user?

**Or how correctly to add the user with all attributes in active directory?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating the user first call SetInfo before setting the password.

Comment: if i call setinfo w/o password - receive error 'The password does not answer rules of a policy of safety' (translate bad)

Comment: Maybe you are missing some mandatory properties such as username (sAMAccountName). If you are using Active Directory consider using the LDAP provider which is preferred.

Comment: Many thanks. Has spent days to understand. Has made through LDAP and function ADsGetObject, all works.